# On Vista or Win7, when PC is domain joined, if I change my user picture is that image stored locally or on the domain?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, active-directory

My question is if Active Directory will cache my user image if I change it locally? I only want the image to be on my local pc, not cached on the domain.

I'm using RTM Windows 7, but I imagine this would apply to Vista as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is stored locally. Not in Active Directory.

<sub>I don't really know how to expand on this</sub>